# Criteria for determing a duplicate question

Tags: discussion, support

I flagged this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814527/add-more-conditions-to-this-update-case-statement) as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734231/mysql-update-case-help).

The flag was declined.

I must be missing something about what qualifies as a duplicate.  How does this fail the criteria for a duplicate question?

Comment: It likely was declined as a result of the [Triage review.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12685738) A "Looks OK" review declines the flags currently on the post, last I checked. Edit: Actually, that does look to be the case. Your "Possible duplicate" comment was added three minutes before the review ended, meaning you flagged about then. So the review declined your flag, and it's likely not a bad flag.

Comment: @Kendra - so in the future, to get a more accurate assessment, I should wait X number of minutes to flag so that it's not declined by a mindless reviewer ?

Comment: How are these duplicates? In the first question, the problem is extending the `case when` from one variable to multiple variables, and the second question never mentions that problem. I am not well versed in MySQL, but to me these questions seem quite different. About the only thing they have in common is that both use `case when`

Comment: Addendum: the question you suggest as the duplication target also seems quite poor; it never really explains what the problem is, just a code dump and "Can anybode tell me how to fix this?". I don' know how it got such  a high score. It seems a bad candidate for a dupe target.

Comment: @devlincarnate That's up to you, whether you want to risk it or not. Not every question goes to Triage, and not ever _new_ question goes to Triage. You'll have to make a judgement call, and if you flag and close voter can always come and cast a vote if you're right. If they do, it won't matter what Triage says, their vote will remain.

Comment: @HugoRune - The OP asks how to add multiple criteria.  But the problem is with the syntax of the CASE statement, not with adding more criteria.  You can see this by looking at the selected answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

Shog9 sums up duplicate eligibility nicely in the [dupehammer post at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/178816)

> Remember: duplicates are questions that ask for a solution to fundamentally identical problems - many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates. By the same token, many questions are asked using very different wordings but seek to solve identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a solution even when they don't know what terms to search for.

So, are these problems fundamentally identical? I am not so sure. I am also not a gold tag badge holder in MySQL, one of those users would be more able to determine if this were fundamentally identical. However, in my opinion they are not. One is looking to compare ids from a set of ids, and the other is looking to compare a single id as well as a set of other columns from the same row and based on that then take some action.